# My Database Not updating This its not even considering my if statement in discord.py

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, discord.py

[image]

Hi i have created a Level system in discord.py 2.0 using postgresql my problem is that even if The statement i have written is true values are not updating

```
@commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, message: discord.Message):
        if message.author.bot is True:
            pass
        else:
            userk = message.author.id
            guildk = message.guild.id
            user = await self.bot.db.fetch("SELECT * FROM levels WHERE user_id = $1 AND guild_id = $2",userk,guildk )
            
            level = await self.bot.db.fetchval("SELECT level FROM levels WHERE user_id = $1 AND guild_id = $2",userk,guildk )
            xp = await self.bot.db.fetchval("SELECT xp FROM levels WHERE user_id = $1 AND guild_id = $2",userk,guildk )
        
        
        
        
        
            if not user :
                await self.bot.db.execute("INSERT INTO levels (level ,xp , user_id,guild_id) VALUES ($1,$2,$3,$4)",1,0,userk,guildk)  
            else:
                
                    if xp > (level+1)*100 is True:
                        levelk = level +1
                        await self.bot.db.execute("UPDATE levels SET level = $1 WHERE xp = $2 AND user_id = $3",levelk,0,userk)
                        await message.reply(embed = discord.Embed(description=f"**Congratulations {message.author.name} You Have Reached Level {level+1}**"))
                    
                    else:
                        await self.bot.db.execute("UPDATE levels SET xp = $1 WHERE user_id = $2",xp +1,userk)
```

as you can see xp is clearly crossed please help me idk what i am doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

Following database modification statements, you should use `await self.bot.db.commit()` to save the changes done to the database; here's how that would look:

```
@commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, message: discord.Message):
        if message.author.bot is True:
            pass
        else:
            userk = message.author.id
            guildk = message.guild.id
            user = await self.bot.db.fetch("SELECT * FROM levels WHERE user_id = $1 AND guild_id = $2",userk,guildk )
            
            level = await self.bot.db.fetchval("SELECT level FROM levels WHERE user_id = $1 AND guild_id = $2",userk,guildk )
            xp = await self.bot.db.fetchval("SELECT xp FROM levels WHERE user_id = $1 AND guild_id = $2",userk,guildk )
        
            if not user :
                await self.bot.db.execute("INSERT INTO levels (level ,xp , user_id,guild_id) VALUES ($1,$2,$3,$4)",1,0,userk,guildk)  
                await self.bot.db.commit() # Here
            else:
                
                    if xp > (level+1)*100 is True:
                        levelk = level +1
                        await self.bot.db.execute("UPDATE levels SET level = $1 WHERE xp = $2 AND user_id = $3",levelk,0,userk)
                        await self.bot.db.commit() # Here
                        await message.reply(embed = discord.Embed(description=f"**Congratulations {message.author.name} You Have Reached Level {level+1}**"))
                    
                    else:
                        await self.bot.db.execute("UPDATE levels SET xp = $1 WHERE user_id = $2",xp +1,userk)
                        await self.bot.db.commit() # Here
```

I've fixed somethings in the code:

```
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_message(self, message: discord.Message):
    if message.author.bot is True:
        pass
    else:
        userk = message.author.id
        guildk = message.guild.id
        user = await self.bot.db.fetchall("SELECT * FROM levels WHERE user_id = ? AND guild_id = ?", (userk, guildk))
        
        level = await self.bot.db.fetchall("SELECT level FROM levels WHERE user_id = ? AND guild_id = ?", (userk, guildk))
        xp = await self.bot.db.fetchall("SELECT xp FROM levels WHERE user_id = ? AND guild_id = ?", (userk, guildk))
    
        if not user :
            await self.bot.db.execute("INSERT INTO levels (level, xp, user_id, guild_id) VALUES (?,?,?,?)", (1, 0, userk, guildk))  
            await self.bot.db.commit()
        else:
            
                if xp > (level + 1) * 100:
                    levelk = level + 1
                    await self.bot.db.execute("UPDATE levels SET level = ? WHERE xp = ? AND user_id = ?", (levelk, 0, userk))
                    await self.bot.db.commit()
                    await message.reply(embed = discord.Embed(description=f"**Congratulations {message.author.name} You Have Reached Level {level+1}**"))
                
                else:
                    await self.bot.db.execute("UPDATE levels SET xp = ? WHERE user_id = ?", ((xp + 1), userk))
                    await self.bot.db.commit()
```

Comment: didnt worked level still not updating

Comment: Edited my answer to include a second fix.

Comment: didnt worked telling syntax error near AND in user and i am not able to see which error
and i am using asyncpg i dont think fetchall works in it